# pandas dataframe aggregate - why does it return column names?

Tags: python, pandas

here's a simple data frame:

```
   Acid  Balance_1  CustID  Balance_2
0     1   0.082627       1        NaN
1     2   0.397579       1   0.459942
2     3   0.201596       2   0.596573
3     4   0.616448       3   0.705697
4     5   0.844865       3   0.483279
5     6        NaN       4   0.360260
```

I have been trying to play around with the aggregate function, after grouping by CustID.

```
groupby_obj = time_series.groupby(["CustID"])
df = groupeby_obj.agg(set)
```

This returns

```
                                             Acid  \
CustID                                              
1       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   
2       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   
3       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   
4       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   

                                        Balance_1  \
CustID                                              
1       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   
2       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   
3       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   
4       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])   

                                        Balance_2  
CustID                                             
1       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])  
2       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])  
3       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])  
4       set([Balance_1, Balance_2, Acid, CustID])
```

instead of what I was thinking it might do:

```
        Acid         Balance_1                    Balance_2
CustID                            
1       set([1,2])   set([0.082627, 0.397579])    set([NaN, 0.459942])
    etc for the other CustIDs...
```

Why is the aggregate filling the data frame with the set of all column headers?

Thanks,
Anne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your frame

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
   Acid  Balance_1  CustID  Balance_2
0     1   0.082627       1        NaN
1     2   0.397579       1   0.459942
2     3   0.201596       2   0.596573
3     4   0.616448       3   0.705697
4     5   0.844865       3   0.483279
5     6        NaN       4   0.360260
```

Here's the groupings that you create

```
In [24]: df.groupby(['CustID']).groups
Out[24]: {1: [0, 1], 2: [2], 3: [3, 4], 4: [5]}
```

Here's a way to see what's being passed to the function (its a frame)

```
In [25]: df.iloc[[0,1]]
Out[25]: 
   Acid  Balance_1  CustID  Balance_2
0     1   0.082627       1        NaN
1     2   0.397579       1   0.459942

In [26]: df.iloc[[2]]
Out[26]: 
   Acid  Balance_1  CustID  Balance_2
2     3   0.201596       2   0.596573
```

And here's what a set operation does on a frame (you get back the list of the columns)
Its not a very interesting/useful operation

```
In [27]: set(df.iloc[[2]])
Out[27]: set(['Balance_1', 'Balance_2', 'Acid', 'CustID'])
```

The point of agg is to aggregate the passed frame to say a Series. Your operation
should reduce the inputs dimensionaility

```
In [28]: df.groupby(['CustID']).agg(lambda x: x.sum())
Out[28]: 
        Acid  Balance_1  Balance_2
CustID                            
1          3   0.480206   0.459942
2          3   0.201596   0.596573
3          9   1.461313   1.188976
4          6        NaN   0.360260
```

What you are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I wasn't really trying to accomplish anything in particular, just playing around to improve my understanding of how pandas works...